# eventId and icalUID of event is getting different, created between outlook calendar and google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, office365

Events created in outlook calendar with google calendar participants
and trying to fetch events from outlook and google calendar separately, but these are getting different id's and icalUID

Is there a way to find these two calendars having same events?

Answer (score 1):

The mapping between iCalUID and EventId is not 1:1 (see https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#iCalUID ).

You can search by iCalUID through calendar API's events.list() with parameter iCalUID: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#iCalUID